# How I can create const char* []

Tags: c++, xcode, c++11, argv

I have code:

```
int ParseCommandLine( int argc, const char* argv[])
{
    string  inFilePath = "";
    string outFilePath = "";

    for( int i = 1; i < argc; ++i )
    {
        if( string( argv[i] ) == "-i" || string( argv[i] ) == "--input")
        {
            // Check for "-i @args" form of reqest.
            if( argc <= 2 )
            {
                ifstream newIn;
                newIn.open(string(argv[++i]));
            
                if(!newIn.is_open())
                {
                    cerr << "Incorrect file path.";
                    return 1;
                }
            
                string buff;
                vector<string> file;
            
                while(newIn >> buff)
                    file.push_back(buff);
            
                char**  arr = new char* [file.size()];
            
                for(int j = 0; j < file.size(); ++j)
                    arr[j] = file[j].c_str();    // Error: Assigning to 'char *' from incompatible type 'const std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> >::value_type *' (aka 'const char *')
            
                ParseCommandLine(file.size(), arr);    // Error No matching function for call to 'ParseCommandLine'
            
                delete[] arr;
                newIn.close();
            
                return 0;
            }
            else
            {
                cerr << "Reqest with --input option can have only one argument." << endl;
                return 1;
        }
    }
```

The function ParseCommandLine getting argc&argv from the main params. This piece of program need to transform new file to const char* argv[] and call the ParseComandLine secondly.

Anybody can help with this problem?

Comment: just change `char` to `const char`

Comment: `arr` needs to be `const char**  arr = new const char* [file.size()];` instead.  Better would be `std::vector<const char*> arr(file.size());` then you don't need `delete[] arr;` anymore

Comment: BTW, `if( argc <= 2 )` is wrong, it should be `if( argc > 2 )` instead

Comment: @RemyLebeau no, it need to be ( argc <= 2 ). In the task if flag -i, you need to check request for 2 argc. Only  -i (flag) and path (argm)

Thanks for ur help with const char. It's working :)

Comment: @Wargos Look again more carefully. Lets assume the command line is `"myapp -i"`, so `argv[]` is `{"myapp","-i"}` and `argc` is 2. `argv[i]` is `"-i"` when `i` is 1, and `if( argc <= 2 )` will be true, so the code will increment `i` to 2 and try to access `argv[2]`, which is out of bounds. If the command line were `"myapp -i path"`, then `argv[]` would be ``{"myapp","-i","path"}`` and `argc` would be 3, so `if ( argc <= 2 )` would be false, skipping the handling of `newIn`. That is why you need to use `if ( argc > 2 )` instead.

Comment: Additionally: What happens if you have another command line parameter? Consider `myapp -v -i` – while you might not have it *now* you maybe add that later. So you might rather check `argc` in relation to `i` – or, as `argv` is null-terminated, check if `argv[i + 1]` is not `nullptr`.

Comment: @RemyLebeau • `argv[argc]` is in bounds, and will be nullptr.  The `argc` doesn't count the extra terminating nullptr.

Comment: @Eljay if the code relies on `argv[]` being NULL-terminated, then there are more bugs in this code, as `string(argv[++i])` could then end up failing since constructing a `std::string` with a NULL pointer is *undefined behavior*, and the code is not NULL-terminating the `arr` array it creates.

Comment: @RemyLebeau • Very true.  But at least the `argv[argc]` access itself is well-defined.  Things just go pear-shaped after that.

Comment: Parse command line is a common task in programming, I just recommend using some libraries like gflags, boost program options.

Comment: @RemyLebeau

Guys, look, the task aiming on creating app, which can operate with same flags, like `-f @filepath`(wile with with we gonna work), `-d`(calc digits in `-f` file) e.t.c

`-i @inFilePath` flag need to be only one in command line. This flag writing with only one argument, `if(argc <= 3)` (yeah, it need to change from 2 to 3) checking it. -i flag setting @inFilePath file like basic command line requests. That is all)

Comment: @RemyLebeau I'm using `if(argc <= 3)` because in the task if u see `-f` flag, it must be ONLY one flag in request

Comment: @Wargos you keep changing the rules of how the parameters should be processed. Why can't you just provide the complete rules up front? In any case, if `-f` must be by itself, then I would use something more like this: `for(....) { if (strcmp(argv[i], "-i") == 0 || ... ) { ... } else if (strcmp(argv[i], "-f") == 0) { if (i != 1 || argc != 3) { ... return 1; } ... } else { ... } }`

Comment: @Wargos also, just like the code is originally missing a push of a null terminator into the end of the `vector` for `argv[argc]`, it is also missing pushing a filename into the front of the `vector` for `argv[0]`. So processing of parameters is inconsistent between 1st and 2nd runs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just change `char` to `const char`